# Getting textbox and checkbox values which is in edit item template of gridview in a string

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, gridview

THis is my vb.net code to update the name of the person whose booked a car and whether he wants ac or non ac car is handled by a checkbox. When i click on the edit button in gridview. I get a textbox to edit person and a checkbox to select car ac type. After clicking on update the textbox code is not retrieving the edited textbox value, it is taking the binded textbox value. Like suppose if i'm editing from Mathew to John, then it takes Mathew it doesnot take the value of John. Similarly with checkbox, even if i check the checkbox. the checked attribute of checkbox is showing false. Please help me with this.

```
Protected Sub gvBooking_RowUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles gvBooking.RowUpdating
            Dim name As String = DirectCast(gvBooking.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("txtperson1"), TextBox).Text

            Dim id As Integer = Integer.Parse(gvBooking.DataKeys(e.RowIndex).Value.ToString)


            Dim carac As String = "False"


            Dim chk As CheckBox = CType(gvBooking.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("CheckBox1"), CheckBox)
            If (chk.Checked = True) Then
                carac = "True"
            End If


            Dim sql As String = ""
            sql = "update dbo.tbl_Book set person_name='" + name + "',ac_type='" + carac + "' where booking_id = " + id.ToString
            gc.ExecuteCommand(sql)
            gvBooking.EditIndex = -1
            gc.BindGridView(gvBooking, "select * from tbl_Book")
        End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check have you bind the grid view in page load outside page post back property